# iMac 2009 too bad

Tags: hard-drive, imac

I have an early 2009 iMac. It was too slow, so I reinstalled the OS. After the installation it appeared to work fine. However it has a strange behaviour. If I try to open Safari it loads instantly, but if I press to update software button it gets blocked and I need to shut down from button. After that it does not even boot anymore.

As I thought it was a hard drive problem I installed a SSD. Now the system runs faster but it gets blocked if I press to update or system preferences for example. I think it can be a software problem, because some things work good and other not.

Perhaps it is because I am trying to install a very old OS. Snow Leopard 10.6.3.

Please any suggestions is highly appreciated and if anyone faces the same problems please share your solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: At least try getting it up to 10.6.8 via the combo updater - https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399 & let us know what happens.

Comment: Even after upgrading to 10.6.8, I would assume software update would not work with current apple servers.

Comment: Hi, @Tetsujin, so I need to first install macOS 10.6.3 and then update to 10.6.8? I imagine to do that it is possible to write that update to a USB. Then do I need to turn on the iMac and press C button, or do I need to boot normally to install the update? Thank you and sorry, I am quite new with MacOS.

Comment: You need 10.6.3 running first, as a working OS; then you run the combo updater [just like a regular app] from inside that OS. It will do the rest.

Comment: Thank you @Tetsujin . I have followed your advice and installed successfully the update. After installing it I rebooted the iMac. I try to do something (click on the Apple logo) and it got blocked. After 1 hour blocked I turned it off. Now it boots but I can do anything. So I imagine I need to reinstall again the OS... You help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I am thinking whether is possible or  not to update to el capitan directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the problem was that with Snow Leopard Safari has an old version that crashes. To update the system the best solution is to create a bootable USB image with MacOS El Capitan and it is very easy to install El Capitan. However, the most difficult thing could be to get El Capitan image.dmg. Here you have a very useful link for that procedure: https://www.cherru.es/como-descargar-osx-el-capitan/